# Save .text file increment

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't figure out why the code don't work properly, when i click on save button show me Yokoso Log(1) then second save is showing Yokoso Log(1).txt(2).txt .....

```
            //Create txt and write

        string logPath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Yokoso Log\\Yokoso Log");
        TextWriter txtwrite = new StreamWriter(logPath);

        int count = 1;

        Find:
        if (File.Exists(logPath))
        {
            logPath = logPath + "(" + count.ToString() + ").txt";
            count++;
            goto Find;
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(logPath);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    txtwrite.Write("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
                }
                txtwrite.WriteLine("");
                txtwrite.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________");

            }
            txtwrite.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Log create successfully (directory desktop).");
        }

    }
```

Comment: … because you are adding to `logPath` in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
var currentPath = logPath;
while (File.Exists(currentPath))
{
  currentPath = logPath + "(" + count.ToString() + ").txt";
  count++;
}

File.Create(currentPath);
...
```

Comment: Thank you i got it.

Answer (score 0):

here you are creating a file

```
TextWriter txtwrite = new StreamWriter(logPath);
```

then when you you check for the file sure enough there is a file

```
if (File.Exists(logPath))
```

this is what I think you mean to do

```
    string logPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Yokoso Log\\Yokoso Log");

    int count = 1;
    while (File.Exists(logPath))
    {
        logPath = logPath + "(" + count.ToString() + ").txt";
        count++;
    }

    using (TextWriter txtwrite = new StreamWriter(logPath))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                txtwrite.Write("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
            }
            txtwrite.WriteLine("");
            txtwrite.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Log create successfully (directory desktop).");
```